# Generate unique variable name for open modal in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I want to generate unique variable `share` in `*ngFor` so I can open single modal.

```
<li *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; let i = index">
  <div class="gallery card" >                        
        <div class="share-fab" (click)="share = !share" [class.open]="share">
           <div class="option email" [class.open]="share"><i class="material-icons">email</i></div>
           <div class="option download" [class.open]="share"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></div>
           <div class="option facebook" [class.open]="share"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i></div>
           <div class="option twitter" [class.open]="share"><i class="material-icons">notifications_none</i></div>
           <div class="close" [class.open]="share"><i class="material-icons cross">close</i></div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

I appreciate any help...

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Perhaps you want to make `share` an array and access it using `share[i]`

Comment: I'm using `share` for open modal but all modals get open, not single... I'll try something with array. Tnx!

Comment: create separate component for  gallery and pass gallery as input to that component. your modal will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a property `share` to your gallery object, for instance:

```
export class Gallery {
   //...
   public share: boolean = false;
}
```

In your template you can do something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; let i = index">
  <div class="gallery card" >                        
        <div class="share-fab" (click)="gallery.share = !gallery.share" [class.open]="gallery.share">
           <div class="option email" [class.open]="gallery.share"><i class="material-icons">email</i></div>
           <div class="option download" [class.open]="gallery.share"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></div>
           <div class="option facebook" [class.open]="gallery.share"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i></div>
           <div class="option twitter" [class.open]="gallery.share"><i class="material-icons">notifications_none</i></div>
           <div class="close" [class.open]="gallery.share"><i class="material-icons cross">close</i></div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Another option would be to create a variable in your component where you keep track of which galleries should be active. Pretty sure you will figure out how to do that yourself :)